# Unable to download and save file from FTP server with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp, zip

I am trying to download a zip file from an FTP server and save it in a temporary directory:

```
agent = Net::FTP.new
agent.connect(host, 21)
agent.login(user, pass)
agent.chdir(path)
agent.passive = true
file = agent.getbinaryfile(source_file, @file_path)
file.save!(@file_path)
```

However, it doesn't save the file because it's a String?

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `save!' for #<String:0x0000000cbc0398>
```

Is there another way to download zip files from an FTP server, or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `getbinaryfile` is enough because [`Net::FTP#getbinaryfile`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-getbinaryfile) will save the content in the specified path.

```
....
agent.getbinaryfile(source_file, @file_path)
```

The exception is thrown because the method returns a string and [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) does not have `save!` method. (`Net::FTP` does not have `save!` method neither)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Do you know if the destination folder has to exist or will it automatically be created if it doesn't?

Comment: @Severin, The `getbinaryfile` will simply use `open`. That will require the destination directory exist.